# Add intuit ipp:login button to single page application with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am working on an single page application using angular, i want to integrate that application with [quick-books](https://developer.intuit.com/). I am trying to add [intuit login button](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0060_authentication_and_authorization/connect_from_quickbooks_apps.com) to my applications's login page but its not rendering it. I tried to create a directive to render that button through it but its not working. Is there any work around for that.

Answer (score 1):

I have integrated "QBO" button into angular SPA. I will try to find this piece of code, but in general it should looks like (don't forget to replace url for your site) :
 :

```
.directive('connectToQuickbooks', function($window){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: "<ipp:connectToIntuit></ipp:connectToIntuit>",
    link: function(scope) {
      var intuitScriptLoaded = function(){
        return $window.intuit 
          && $window.intuit.ipp 
          && $window.intuit.ipp.anywhere 
          && $window.intuit.ipp.anywhere.setup;
      };

      if (intuitScriptLoaded()) {
        $window.intuit.ipp.anywhere.init();
      } else {
        var script = $window.document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "//js.appcenter.intuit.com/Content/IA/intuit.ipp.anywhere.js";
        $window.document.body.appendChild(script);
      }

      scope.$watch(
        intuitScriptLoaded,
        function(newValue, oldValue) {
          if(intuitScriptLoaded()) {
            $window.intuit.ipp.anywhere.setup({
              grantUrl: '/'
            });
          }
        }
      );
    }
  }
});
```